# How to replace only elements found using a python re.findall rather than entire string?

Tags: python, regex

How would I replace groups found using the python regex findall method without having to change the rest of the string too.

For example:

```
import re
repl1='k1'
repl2='k2'
pattern=re.compile('CN=Root,Model=.*,Vector=Reactions\[(.*)\],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=(.*),Reference=Value')
```

I want use the re.sub to replace ONLY the elements within the `(.*)` with `repl1` and `repl1` rather than having to change the rest of the string too.

-------edit -----

The output I want should look like this:

```
output = 'CN=Root,Model=.*,Vector=Reactions[k1],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=k2,Reference=Value')
```

But note I have left the `'.*'` in  after `model` because this will change every time. I.e. this can be anything.

----------edit 2----------

The input is a simple one line which is almost exactly the same at `pattern`. For example:

```
input= 'CN=Root,Model=Model1,Vector=Reactions\[k10],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=k12,Reference=Value')
```

Comment: An example along with expected output would be better.

Comment: No problem - I've made some edits

Comment: Should there always be one replacement each for `repl1` and `repl2` or how do you intend to distinguish when each should be replaced?

Comment: [Like this](https://ideone.com/gmhT13)?

Comment: Yes, repl1 and repl2 are always only one item long (if this is what you mean). I'm using this within a loop over many files (eventually) but only concerning myself with one replacement at the moment

Comment: I think you left an extra backslash in your "required output" string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.sub`'s argument `repl` can be a one-argument function, and in that case it is called with the match object as an argument. So, if you ensure that all parts of the pattern are in a group you should have all the information you need to replace the old string with the new one.

```
import re

repl1='k1'
repl2='k2'
pattern=re.compile('(CN=Root,Model=.*,Vector=Reactions\[)(.*)(\],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=)(.*)(,Reference=Value)')
target = 'CN=Root,Model=something,Vector=Reactions[somethingelse],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=1234,Reference=Value'
```

Now define a function that produces the matched string with groups 1 and 3 replaced with your desired values:

```
def repl(m):
    g = list(m.groups())
    g[1] = repl1
    g[3] = repl2
    return "".join(g)
```

Passing this function as the first argument to `re.sub` than achieves the desired transformation:

```
pattern.sub(repl, target)
```

gives the result

```
'CN=Root,Model=something,Vector=Reactions[k1],ParameterGroup=Parameters,Parameter=k2,Reference=Value'
```